# Multiple If statements in one ArcGIS Arcade Expression

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I'm trying to get this popup expression to work in ArcGIS Online using ArcGIS Arcade.

```
if ($feature["Road_Work_Ahead_Deployed"] >= 1){
    return "Road Work Ahead Deployed: " + $feature["Road_Work_Ahead_Deployed"]
}
+ TextFormatting.NewLine + 
if ($feature["LCA_Velcro_Deployed"] >= 1){
    return "LCA Velcro: " + $feature["LCA_Velcro_Deployed"]
}
```

I do something very similar in ArcMap using VBscript but I can't seem to make it work in ArcGIS Arcade. Is it possible to chain statements together like this in one expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a string variable, build it out, and return it at the end, instead of multiple returns:

```js
var result = ""
if ($feature["Road_Work_Ahead_Deployed"] >= 1){
    result += "Road Work Ahead Deployed: " + $feature["Road_Work_Ahead_Deployed"]
}

if (($feature["Road_Work_Ahead_Deployed"] >= 1) && ($feature["LCA_Velcro_Deployed"] >= 1)){
    result += TextFormatting.NewLine
}
if ($feature["LCA_Velcro_Deployed"] >= 1){
    result += "LCA Velcro: " + $feature["LCA_Velcro_Deployed"]
}
return result
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect, instead of the second if statement though I'll add the line break into the result for each statement. I need to add more if statements than just the two I posted as an example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`IIf()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/logical_functions/#iif) function and return an empty string (`""`) or `null` when the condition is false, and use [`Concatenate()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/text_functions/#concatenate) to join both terms (although the `+` operator also works):

```js
var var1 = $feature["Road_Work_Ahead_Deployed"]
var str1 = IIf(var1 >= 1, "Road Work Ahead Deployed: " + var1, null)

var var2 = $feature["LCA_Velcro_Deployed"]
var str2 = IIf(var2 >= 1, "LCA Velcro: " + var2, null)

return Concatenate([str1, str2], TextFormatting.NewLine)
//OR: return str1 + TextFormatting.NewLine + str2
```